# Thyroid Peroxidase (TPO) Ab Test- normal or abmormal

Tags: endocrinology, thyroid, hyperthyroid, thyroperoxidase-tpo

I had a variety of test ran on my thyroid and I'm waiting to see the DR. My question is the TPOAb reference rang is 0-34. Mine came back as 9 IU/ml. Is this still considered normal or abnormal? I also have a family history of HyperT and HypoT (not sure if that matters) Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your post and welcome to Health SE! However, post asking personal medical advice are not usually accepted on the site as we do not have the resources to answer them completely and they are very important as they regard your health. Consulting the proper medical authorities would be the best course of action for you and I am sorry that is all we can do. Thank you!

Comment: Ok....Thanks. Let me see if I can rephrase my question. If a reference range is 0-34, Would 9 be considered negative? (Not sure if its allowed this way) I do see my DR in a few days.

Comment: Not sure what your asking, but as long as its not refering to anyone specific you should be fine. All I and my phrases should be avoided. We can evaluate the question again after editing and if it's within guidelines you should be all set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Normal.** A result of 9 where the reference range is 0 - 34 indicates that you're within the normal range. For this test, an abnormal result would be a value over 34 because it's not possible to have a result below zero.

Keep in mind that each testing lab can different reference ranges, and they can differ over time too.